# Understanding the behaviour of at + x minutes

Tags: at

When I run

`echo "hello" | at now + 7 minutes`

I get the following output -

`job 2 at 2016-12-11 05:06`

However when I use

`bash txt | at now + 7 minutes`

It starts executing immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash command is invoking the script now and doesn't have anything to pipe to the at command.

```
cat txt | at now + 7 minutes
```

will pass the lines of the bash script to at

Answer (score 1):

you can use this too :

```
at -f txt now + 7 minutes
```